# Can you setup a path alias for a reference outside the root directory

Tags: typescript, configuration

I am working on a typescript project with the following directory structure

```
├── common
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── Schemas
│   └── Types
├── server
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── src
│   └── test
└── viewer
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── src
    └── tests
```

I have successfully setup a reference to the common directory in the server and viewer `tsconfig.json` this way

```json
"references": [
    { "path": "../common" }
]
```

so I can include common files with

```
import EventListSchema from '../../../../common/Schemas/EventList';
```

However, I would like to setup a path alias like I have for `src`

```json
"paths": {
    "@/*": [ "src/*" ],
    "common/*": [ "../common/*" ] // something like this
},
```

so I can include common files with a simpler path like

```
import EventListSchema from 'common/Schemas/EventList';
```

when I tried to add `common` to `paths` I get this error

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'common/Schemas/EventList' or its corresponding type declarations.

import EventListSchema from 'common/Schemas/EventList';
```

Is something like this possible? I am using `tsc` version 4.0.2

Comment: I want to to the same thing. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I did not find a solution. I can't remember if I found that it was not possible or did not find anything. sorry...

Answer (score -1):

What the alias does is to do the path replacement. In your example,

```
"paths": {
    "@/*": [ "src/*" ],
    "common/*": [ "../common/*" ] // something like this
},
```

```
import EventListSchema from 'common/Schemas/EventList';
```

The typescript compiler will replace the path to be

```
import EventListSchema from '../common/Schemas/EventList';
```

As your EventListSchema file is not at its root directory, the path reference is not correct.

Instead, do it like this

```
"paths": {
    "@/*": [ "src/*" ],
    "common/*": [ "src/../../common" ]
},
```

Also, remember to assign the alias in both `tsconfig.json` and the build config files (e.g. for Vue.js: `webpack.config.js`, `vue.config.js`, or `vite.config.js`).